# Can I dispose CancellationTokenSource before Task be cancelled?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

can I dispose `CancellationTokenSource` before `Task` be cancelled? If not, why?

**Code 1** (from [Task Cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation). I made some minor changes for simplification) seems to recommend to wait `Task` before disposing `CancellationTokenSource`. If so, the `Dispose` method of the class containing `CancellationTokenSource` will be more complicated than I hope it to be.

On my PC, **Code 2** seems to be working properly, too. Can I use this pattern instead?

**Code 1: Dispose AFTER Cancellation Complete**

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main() {
        var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = DoAsync(tokenSource2.Token);
        tokenSource2.Cancel();
        tokenSource2 = null;

        try {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e) {
            foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + v.Message);
        }
        finally {
            tokenSource2.Dispose();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task DoAsync(CancellationToken token) {
        while (true) {
            await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(true);
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
```

**Code 2: Dispose BEFORE Cancellation Complete**

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main() {
        var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = DoAsync(tokenSource2.Token);
        tokenSource2.Cancel();
        tokenSource2.Dispose();

        try {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e) {
            foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + v.Message);
        }
        finally {
            //// tokenSource2.Dispose();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task DoAsync(CancellationToken token) {
        while (true) {
            await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(true);
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
```

## EDIT: My case

Actually I'm wondering whether I have to `Wait` for task cancellation in `Dispose` method.

```
    public class Class1 : IDisposable {
        //// tokenSource for calculationTask
        private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

        //// background calculation task
        private Task calculationTask;

        public void Dispose() {
            tokenSource?.Cancel();
            //// calculationTask.Wait(); Should I wait for task completion?
            tokenSource?.Dispose();
            tokenSource = null;

            calculationTask = null;
        }
    }
```